# mongoosastic after reindex data is not updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoosastic

`mongosastic` is not updating data if I synchronize data again.

```
  let stream = obj.model.synchronize(obj.query);
  let count = 0;
  stream.on('data', function(err, doc) {
    count++;
    grunt.log.writelns(count);
  });
  stream.on('close', function() {
    grunt.log.write('close');
    cb(null, count);
  });
  stream.on('error', function(err) {
    grunt.log.write('error');
    cb(err);
  });
```

How I can reindex after data is created on elasticSearch.

One options I have is to delete and save data again. Any thoughts?

Comment: Mongoosastic is buggy and we found out it doesn't work well. So my friend Jbdemonte created [Mongoose-Elasticsearch-XP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-elasticsearch-xp) (that we call Mexp) that works much better. I completely dropped Mongoosastic since then.

Comment: Thanks buddy, re-indexing works, but have to create `indexes` first on elastic search.

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks for linking it. It really does work better (also migration is very easy :) )